# Error while connecting MongoDB, connect using MongloClient.connect(url) with Automation Script

Tags: node.js, mongodb

(MongoClient.connect(url),function (err, dbConnection))
this line is being skipped while execution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without additional context and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there is little anyone can do to help. Please *edit* your question to include some context on your problem.

Comment: Please add some extra detail to help us understand your problem.